# Can I limit the memory usage of bufferevents in libevent?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, memory, libevent

Does `libevent` have a way to restrict the memory usage or the outstanding unwritten data with the `bufferevents` API? Alternatively, what happens when libevent runs out of memory?

My application reads data from a file, parses it, and sends it over the network (pseudocode below, my application is C++):

`for line in file:
    host = parse_host(line)
    socket[host].send(line)`

Previously, I split this up into two threads to ensure that we don't block the parsing of the file unnecessarily if one host is slow:

`for line in file:
    host = parse_host(line)
    fixed_sized_queues[host].append(line)`

`while stillParsingFile():
    sockets.poll(timeout=1s)
    for queue in fixed_sized_queues:
       if queue is not Empty and socket[queue.host] is ReadyForWrite:
          socket[queue.host].send(q.pop())`

The logic for the second thread is very clunky, and I thought it would be better to use libevents:

`for line in file:
    host = parse_host(line)
    bufferevents[host].add(line)`

My understanding is that appending to a `bufferevent` is non-blocking (i.e. it will do dynamic memory allocation and asynchronously write the data to the socket). How do I prevent the parse thread from outpacing the network and filling up all of memory by allocating space for data that can't be sent yet?

The ideas I have currently are:

- Use `evbuffer_add_reference` to mitigate the memory usage (still doesn't provide a bound, but at least allocations should be small)
- Use `event_set_mem_functions` and custom locking to force `libevent` to block and wait for memory when it hits a cap (this sounds very dangerous, as it only works if `libevent` only does allocations when adding to a `bufferevent` and nowhere else)
- In the parse thread, grab a lock before adding to the `evbuffer` and check `evbuffer_get_length()`; in the send thread, signal the parse thread in a low water write callback from `libevent`.

Comment: I spy `bufferevent_setwatermark`.

Comment: Yeah, after writing up everything that looks like an obvious winner. I'm kinda hoping that someone more experienced with libevent has a better solution, though.